# Image to pencilsketch using graphicsmagick

Tags: graphicsmagick

I am new to imageprocessing. I want to convert an image to pencilsketch. I want to know how can i achieve the same with Graphicsmagick. Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would be somewhat easier with **ImageMagick** than **GraphicsMagick**, as Anthony Thyssen has put together some excellent examples - but they rely on **ImageMagick** capabilities such as *"aside-processing"* in parentheses which **GraphicsMagick** lacks. They are [here](http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/photos/#color-in).

However, you can do fairly simplistic stuff with **GraphicsMagick**. Let's start with this picture of the White House:

[image]

```
gm convert whitehouse.jpg -edge 1 -negate -normalize -colorspace Gray -blur 0x0.5 sketch.png
```

[image]